# Calculating error for $\pi$ in an expansion

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, approximation, pi

I have the following equation: $\quad\pi = 4\arctan(1/2) + 4\arctan(1/3).$

> I want to calculate how many terms of the expansion ($n$) I have to calculate in order for the error to be less than  $10^{-10}$.

I have an idea for the method to be used:

Taking the power series of $\arctan(x)$ and using the remainder integral of the form $$R_n \;=\; \int\frac{{(-1)^n t^{2n}}}{1+t^2}\,dt.$$

So I want the sum of the two remainders from the expansion of each $\arctan(x)$ to be $<$ $\frac{10^{-10}}{4}$.

$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{{(-1)^n t^{2n}}}{1+t^2}\,dt \;+\; \int_0^{1/3}\frac{{(-1)^n t^{2n}}}{1+t^2}\,dt\;<\; \frac{10^{-10}}{4}.$$

Now to solve this, I can't do without making approximations since $t^{2n} > \frac{{(-1)^n t^{2n}}}{1+t^2}$ on my intervals; I approximate using this, getting $$\int_0^{1/2}t^{2n}\,dt \;+\; \int_0^{1/3}t^{2n}\,dt.$$

Evaluating, I get $$\frac{(1/2)^{2n+1}}{2n+1} + \frac{(1/3)^{2n+1}}{2n+1} < \frac{10^{-10}}{4}.$$

I have no idea how to solve this. Would I make another approximation? Or is my method completely wrong to start with.

*Edit:*
After making some huge approximations i.e. getting rid of the $2n+1$'s on the denominator and setting $1/3$ to be $1/2$, I got that $2n+1 =36.$ However, I am not sure whether this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Taylor expansion of $\arctan=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}$ is an alternating series, the error is less than the abs value of the first term neglected, that is equivalent to find an $n$ such that
$$\frac{4 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}+\frac{4 \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}=\frac{1}{10^{10}}$$
Using *Mathematica* I got an approximated value of $n=16$. Indeed
$$4 \sum _{n=1}^{16} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}+4 \sum _{n=1}^{16} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}\approx 3.14159 265357$$
While $\pi\approx 3.14159265358$.

Error is $1.14\times10^{-11}<10^{-10}$

Comment: I just got the value of n to be around 17 due to a calculation error. So would you say that my method is valid?

Comment: @Govind75 Yep. For some reason your series starts from $n=0$ therefore it is OK that you get 17 and me 16. The real issue is that you don't need all the integral mess. It is an alternating series and the error is less than the abs value of the first term neglected

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, you want to find $n$ such that $$R_n=\frac{4 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}+\frac{4 \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}\leq{10^{-k}}$$
$$\frac{8 \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1} < R_n <\frac{8 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}$$ So, let us try to find the solution for
$$\frac{8\, x^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}\leq{10^{-k}}\implies2n-1 \geq 8 \,x^{2 n-1}\, 10^k$$ The only explicit solution is
$$n=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\frac{W\left(-8\, 10^k \log (x)\right)}{\log (x)}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

For your case $(k=10)$ : with $x=\frac 12$, it gives, as a real, $n=16.1267$ and for $x=\frac 13$, it gives $n=10.5598$. In fact, using algebra, the exact value would be $15.6491$